# optical flow for moving object: few points

Tags: opencv, opticalflow

I'm trying to do something like this:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=MIYt1yNwoZU

and I'm on the right way, it works well for 2 hours coding. But I have some question:

- I'm using opencv 2.4 and there are some options around.. see [here](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/video/doc/video.html). which one is the best? lucas kanade with some automatic feature detection? or maybe a simple global orientation is enough? or even kalman filter? for now I'm using a dense farneback’s algorithm and i think is the first (= more simple) option but maybe is not the best one.
- after calculating optical flow on the image (scaled down by factor of 2 for calculating optical flow because it is an hard work) I take the average of the vectors. normal average, summing all of them and dividing from the number of vectors. so with a nested for loop on flow mat. better way?

  ```
  Point2f average_motion(0,0); float n=1;

  for(int y = 0; y < flow.rows; y += step)
      for(int x = 0; x < flow.cols; x += step) {

          const Point2f& fxy = flow.at<Point2f>(y, x);

          if( abs(fxy.x) > threshold || abs(fxy.y) > threshold) {
              average_motion += fxy;
              n++;
          }

      }
   average_motion *= 1/n;

   average_motion *= 1/n;
   cout << average_motion << endl;
  ```
- I'm moving the rects BUT the right/left movement seems to be a little bit weird, instead the up/down works really nice! someone can explain me why?
- translating is ok, but i'm stuck on rotating.. if i get the average vector how can i get the degree? I've tried with angle between vectors with X axis but is does not work nice. some hint?
- Now I'm drawing stuff with opencv drawing api but from 2.4 there is also opengl support.. and should be nice, but i don't find example on that..

Comment: Have you tried using pose estimation functions to get rotation/translation?  Perhaps [estimateRigidTransform](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html)?

Answer (score 4):

The best approach for optical flow is using a Kalman filter for predicting the movement, so you can project the patches in that directions and reduce the searching area for the next frame. Increasing computational speed.

The bad news is that it is a difficult task to make Kalman filter track properly.

Answer (score 2):

I would propse the use the Lucas Kanade method because it is quite fast. Or you could use the GPU implementation of the [RLOF](http://www.nue.tu-berlin.de/menue/forschung/projekte/rlof/), which is similar to the Lucas Kanade. Do not estimate a dense motion vector field just estimate motion vectors for a grid (e.g. each 5th pixel) this saves you a lot of runtime. Or seed the features to track regarding your rectangles you want to move. To move your rectangle it would be a more elegant to estimate transformation matrices e.g. affine or perspective by cv::getPerspectiveTransform or cv::getAffineTransform. The affine transformation contains translation, rotation, and scaling and the perspective contains also scheering. (By both RANSAC is a good estimator). The new positions of the rectangle points could be easly computed by matrix operation.

[x,y,1] = Matrix * [x_old, y_old, 1], see OpenCV documentation